# error: Compression support not enabled in liblas configuration

Tags: installation, lidar, liblas, laz, laszip

I am using `liblas` 1.8.1 and `laszip` 3.1.1 on Mac OS High Sierra. Both were installed using `brew install <package>`. I am looking to get information from a laz file using the following command:

```
lasinfo lazfile.laz
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
error: Compression support not enabled in liblas configuration
```

Assuming `liblas` allows working with laz files, how can I resolve this error and work with laz files in `liblas`?

Comment: It sounds like an issue with the LibLAS *prior* to installation, this could be because the ZIP handler is not supported on Mac or that the distribution you have downloaded has ZIP turned off and downloading from a different source might fix it - or alternately you might need to install a 3rd party ZIP handler (that sort of thing should be in the release notes) ; you could use a PC to convert your LAZ to LAS, from there you shouldn't have any difficulty.

Comment: Have you checked this [link](https://github.com/libLAS/libLAS/issues/115)? It has a similar question (with an answer) as yours.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see `liblas` installed from `brew`, it does not include flags `WITH_LASZIP` or `WITH_STATIC_LASZIP` on build.

See: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/liblas.rb